# image compress process get out of memory error

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm running a multi thread image compressing process. The original file is 1280x
960 high resolution PNG file, about 1800KB. I need compress to <70KB JPEG file. When I process few vehicles, the process runs fine. when I process over 20 vehicles, I start to get out of memory error. Here is the code.

private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
        {
            int j;
            ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
            encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
            {
                if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                    return encoders[j];
            }
            return null;
        }

```
    public static void SaveAsJpg(string inFilePath = null, string outputFileName = null, long compression = 70, long quality = 70)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image orgimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(inFilePath);
        var imgIn = new Bitmap(orgimage);
        var imgOut = new Bitmap(imgIn.Width, imgIn.Height);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imgOut);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.DrawImage(imgIn, 0, 0, imgIn.Width, imgIn.Height);

        EncoderParameters encoding = new EncoderParameters(2);
        encoding.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, compression);
        encoding.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
        ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

        imgOut.Save(outputFileName, myImageCodecInfo, encoding);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to dispose the graphic objects before leaving the method.

```
g.Dispose();
orgiImage.Dispose();
imgIn.Dispose();
imgOut.Dispose();
```

[Disposing System.drawing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403813/disposing-of-system-drawing-objects)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I totally forgot to dispose the graphic objects.